# Write into File with Entries of an Array (Applescript)

Tags: arrays, file, applescript

i have an Array with:

```
set Array to {"AA", "AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BC", "CA", "CB", "CC"}
```

now, when i use

```
do shell script " echo " & Array & " >> " & PathToFile
```

then i get the Result without any spaces or something else

> AAABACBABBBCCACBCC

when i use

```
repeat with counter from 1 to length of Array
    do shell script " echo " & item counter of Array & " >> " & PathToFile
end repeat
```

i get the result, but every entry in a new line:

```
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC
```

But what i want is to write the following Line into my File, with seperators and spaces:

> "AA"; "AB"; "AC"; "BA"; "BB"; "BC"; "CA"; "CB"; "CC"

what i have to do?

Comment: FYI In **AppleScript** that is called a [`list`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE), not an _array_.

Answer (score 1):

> But what i want is to write the following Line into my File, with separators and spaces:
>
> "AA"; "AB"; "AC"; "BA"; "BB"; "BC"; "CA"; "CB"; "CC"

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set myList to {"AA", "AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BC", "CA", "CB", "CC"}
set itemCount to (length of myList)
set myProcessedList to {}

repeat with i from 1 to itemCount
    if i is less than itemCount then
        copy "\"" & item i of myList & "\"; " to end of myProcessedList
    else if i is equal to itemCount then
        copy "\"" & item i of myList & "\"" to end of myProcessedList
    end if
end repeat

set myProcessedListAsString to myProcessedList as string

do shell script "echo " & myProcessedListAsString's quoted form & " > /path/to/file"
```

---

The contents of `/path/to/file` will contain:

```
"AA"; "AB"; "AC"; "BA"; "BB"; "BC"; "CA"; "CB"; "CC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of strings but you want to save **one** string, so you have to join the list. This is quite easy with `text item delimiters`

```
set theList to {"AA", "AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BC", "CA", "CB", "CC"}
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "; "}
set theString to theList as text
set text item delimiters to TID

try 
    set fd to open for access PathToFile with write permission
    write theString to fd as «class utf8»
    close access fd
on error
    try
       close access PathToFile
    end try
end try
```

The result is

```
AA; AB; AC; BA; BB; BC; CA; CB; CC
```

I doubt that you really want to have double quotes in the file. However if you do need double quotes use this

```
set theList to {"AA", "AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BC", "CA", "CB", "CC"}
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "\"; \""}
set theString to theList as text
set text item delimiters to TID

try 
    set fd to open for access PathToFile with write permission
    write (quote & theString & quote) to fd as «class utf8»
    close access fd
on error
    try
       close access PathToFile
    end try
end try
```